# Can we create a custom class to use it in module_drawer paramter in qr.make_image() method

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, coding-style, qr-code, qrcoder

I need a solution which takes input as either svg file or png file and. Based on that we need to change the pattern on qr code , let me provide the input and output for reference input:[input will be in png or else svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWDfJ.png) 
Svg file output :[output qr code with pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10OqW.png)

Modules used are qr code in python

I tried with this custom eye code which I used with module drawer but not working as expected https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/issues/237

```
import qrcode

from qrcode.image.styledpil import StyledPilImage

qr = qrcode.QRCode(error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H)

qr.add_data('http://www.medium.com')

qr_inner_eyes_img = qr.make_image(image_factory-StyledPilImage,

Module_drawer=StarModuleDrawer(), color_mask=SolidFillColorMask(back_color=(255, 255, 255), front_color=(63, 42, 86))) qr_inner_eyes_img.save(f"(base_path}/final_image.png")
```